# Emulating African village fractals with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, fractals

(Question inspired by this [TED Talk](https://www.ted.com/talks/ron_eglash_on_african_fractals) - more info [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190224073839/http://homepages.rpi.edu:80/%7Eeglash/eglash.dir/afractal/afarch.htm))

I'm developing a jQuery plugin to draw images on a canvas in such a way that suggests the fractal-like layout of certain African villages:

[image: African village]
<sub>(source: [eglash at homepages.rpi.edu](https://homepages.rpi.edu/%7Eeglash/eglash.dir/afractal/2.1.5.gif))</sub>

Given a list of image sources, the plugin works like this:

1. Generate a orthogonally-oriented, fractal-like structure similar to the image above.
2. For each discrete region (rectangle) in the structure, draw an image from the list in that region.

Drawing each image is easy enough, but I'm stuck on how to generate the structure. The math that goes into describing fractals is pretty far over my head.

Ideally, getting a fractal representation would be as simple as passing the canvas dimensions to a function, which would return a list of rectangles. Each rectangle would be represented as:

- X/Y coordinates for the top-left corner (relative to canvas)
- width
- height

**How might I implement such a function?**

Comment: Upvoting because this is an interesting question. Although, you should not really be asking for software library recommendations on this site. Might I suggest that you rephrase this question that instead of asking for a library that does X, instead ask about how to implement the algorithm behind X. That should make this question more suited for SO, or [programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the author is asking for help writing code rather than resolving problems with written code.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote @bguiz. I've rephrased the question.

Comment: @acobster I'm going to have to agree with Mike here. It's an interesting question, but the format isn't right for SO. If you create an implementation and then have a specific question about it, that could work.

Comment: Looks like a great question for [codegolf.stackexchange.com](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: hey! i just saw your question was closed. maybe my answer is useful anyways...

Answer (score 1):

there is a important class of fractals called an [L-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system). roughly the idea is to not think about the whole structure too much, but instead to think only about one tiny bit of it and how to attach a smaller version of the same thing to itself.

one great example is a tree. maybe until now when you would describe a tree you'd say "well, it's a tree. it has a root. and from the root the branches grow. and from that the leaves grow". but there's another way to describe a tree by rules:

first define a stick. a stick has some position in space, a length and is rotated in some direction. now to the rule: take a stick. attach 5 to 10 sticks alternately rotated to the left and the right. repeat the procedure for your new sticks. keep doing this until you are tired. incredibly you end up with something that looks like a plant of some sort.

[image: Fractal weeds example from wikipedia]

the different parameters affect the visual appearance of your digital plant. the rotation of a stick attached to another stick might make the tree appear more bushy or more narrow. the position of the attached sticks will change what kind of plant you're getting. attaching all the "child-sticks" to the far end will make it look like a normal tree. spacing things out more evenly will make it look more like a fern (as in the picture). and so forth. the nice thing is you're not limited by reality.

anyways, all of this is theory. i've written up a bunch of code and added some comments to it, but it's hopefully quite a straightforward implementation of what i explained above with boxes instead of sticks.

[click here to play with a jsfiddle of this code](http://jsfiddle.net/9583V/). hit run a few times to see the different results it produces.

```
// a ton of colors. always handy! 
var colors = ["AliceBlue","AntiqueWhite","Aqua","Aquamarine","Azure","Beige","Bisque","Black","BlanchedAlmond","Blue","BlueViolet","Brown","BurlyWood","CadetBlue","Chartreuse","Chocolate","Coral","CornflowerBlue","Cornsilk","Crimson","Cyan","DarkBlue","DarkCyan","DarkGoldenRod","DarkGray","DarkGreen","DarkKhaki","DarkMagenta","DarkOliveGreen","DarkOrange","DarkOrchid","DarkRed","DarkSalmon","DarkSeaGreen","DarkSlateBlue","DarkSlateGray","DarkTurquoise","DarkViolet"]; 

// store base structure here
// in the end this will contain a nested representation of your village
base = {
    x: 0, 
    y: 0, 
    width: 400, 
    height: 400, 
    children: []
}; 

// and a flat structure here, that's always handy too 
var boxes = [base];  

// add some children to the base recursively. 
addChildren( base, 0 ); 

// now create a div for each
for( var i in boxes ){
    var box = boxes[i]; 
    var el = document.createElement("div"); 
    el.className = "box"; 
    el.style.left = box.x + "px"; 
    el.style.top = box.y + "px"; 
    el.style.width = box.width + "px"; 
    el.style.height = box.height + "px"; 
    el.style.backgroundColor = colors[i%colors.length]; 
    document.body.appendChild( el ); 
}


// randomly add children to a box recursively
function addChildren( box, level ){
    // maybe... split vertically? (two next to each other)
    if( Math.random() < 0.5 ){
        // maybe... nest further in the top? 
        if( Math.random() < 1-level/10.0 ){
            box.children.push( {
                x: box.x, 
                y: box.y, 
                width: box.width/2, 
                height: box.height, 
                children: []
            } ); 
        }
        // maybe bottom too? 
        if( Math.random() < 1-level/10.0 ){
            box.children.push( {
                x: box.x + box.width/2, 
                y: box.y, 
                width: box.width/2, 
                height: box.height, 
                children: []
            } ); 
        }
    }
    // ah. maybe we split horizontally instead
    else{
        // maybe... nest further in the top? 
        if( Math.random() < 1-level/10.0 ){
            box.children.push( {
                x: box.x, 
                y: box.y, 
                width: box.width, 
                height: box.height/2, 
                children: []
            } ); 
        }
        // maybe bottom too? 
        if( Math.random() < 1-level/10.0 ){
            box.children.push( {
                x: box.x, 
                y: box.y + box.height/2, 
                width: box.width, 
                height: box.height/2, 
                children: []
            } ); 
        }
    }

    // also add all the children to our 
    // flat list of boxes
    for( var i in box.children ){
        boxes.push( box.children[i] ); 
    }

    // unless we reach level 5 subdivide further! 
    if( level < 5 ){

        for( var i in box.children ){
            // nest deeper! 
            addChildren( box.children[i], level+1 ); 
        }
    } 
}
```

the `addChildren` function is where the magic happens. it randomly decides whether to split the box horizontally or vertically in two. then it randomly decides whether to add a box to the top/left and/or bottom/right. this is where you'll want to make some modifications and play with different criteria. for instance you might get interresting results if you always split horizontally when `level` is an even number, and vertically if it's odd. and so and and so forth.

bottomless wonders spring from simple rules, repeated without end. 
as benoit mandelbrot said :)

good luck, fractals are great!

---

ps. i know this code doesn't produce the result as in your picture. you'll probably spend hours tweaking the if-conditions to get it to do what you want to and it might be a good idea to make yourself an interface with a few sliders to experiment with different settings. or maybe you want to split into three instead of one or two boxes sometimes. the possibilities are too endless for an answer that has already gotten quite long :)